# Ardiuno DUE board. Sketch uploading Error

Tags: arduino-due, sketch, uploading

I am working on Arduino UDE board in Ubuntu 18.04. I've followed following link tutorial.

[https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoDue#:~:text=Use%20your%20Arduino%20Due%20on%20the%20Arduino%20Desktop%20IDE,the%20Arduino%20Boards%20Manager%20page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoDue#:%7E:text=Use%20your%20Arduino%20Due%20on%20the%20Arduino%20Desktop%20IDE,the%20Arduino%20Boards%20Manager%20page).

In Ardiuno IDE I am getting as /dev/ttyS4. Also, I've gone with follwing procedure :

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout username
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyS4
ls -l /dev/ttyS4
```

This gave the following outpit

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 4, 68 Jun 17 17:26 /dev/ttyS4
```

And I am getting following error while uploading sketch though Ardiuno IDE :

```
Sketch uses 11092 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 524288 bytes.
Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port /dev/ttyS4
/home/user/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/bossac/1.6.1-arduino/bossac -i -d --port=ttyS4 -U false -e -w -v -b /tmp/arduino_build_718911/ardiuno_to_python.ino.bin -R 
Send auto-baud
No device found on ttyS4
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
Set binary mode
```

I've tried following solution of decreasing baudrate to 1200 by following command line mulitple times till I get output as 1200 :

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS4 speed 1200 cs8 -cstopb -parenb
```

Still I am facing the error while uploading sketch. I've tried pressing reset and erase buttons few seconds but still not getting anything. Can anyone please help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved. The cable came with my Arduino was charge only , I tried data transfer cable and it worked. This is so dumb. sorry for wasting your time.